# tableView.beginUpdates() behaves weirdly

Tags: swift, uitableview

**The situation (with Swift 4.0 & > iOS10.0)**

- I have a TableView with sections and rows. Each cell has only one
  label and is configured to adapt its height to its label's height
  thanks to auto-layout.
- When a cell is clicked on, it displays another String that may not be
  of the same size (hence not the same number of lines). **I am having
  trouble animating properly the cell so when it is clicked on, it
  adapts its height to display properly the new label**.

**Attempts**

1. Reloading the whole table view displaying the new data for the selected
   cell works fine but it is not what I am trying to achieve.
2. I have tried `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` (with and without a completion handler). When **I click on the cell, it works as expected for the selected cell but the other cells and all sections jump and/or disappear**. This behaviour is very strange and looks like I am messing with forbidden functions but the behaviour is what I am looking for.
3. I have tried `.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`. It behaves  almost exactly as `tableView.beginUpdates()` (and it reloads the tableView, which I prefer to avoid).
4. I have tried attempts n°2 & n°3 with `layoutIfNeeded()` and `layoutSubviews()`, it does not help.

**Code sample**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
  {
   // Attempt n°2
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.endUpdates()

   // Attempt n°3 (alternatively to attempt n°2)
   tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
  }
```

**Questions:**

**Is `tableView.beginUpdates()` the best way to solve my issue? If so, how should I use it ? If not, what is the proper way to animate the cell ?**.

Comment: Looking at "it adapts its height to display properly the new label". Do you have anything happening in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Also. Usually begin and end updates used to wrap around reloadRows. So you should try: `beginUpdates() reloadRows() endUpdates()`

Comment: No, I have nothing going on in 'heightForRowAtIndexPath'. Going to wrap around 'reloadRows()'

Comment: Wrapping `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` around `reloadRows` does not work for me.

Comment: Okay. So what you have to do is use `heightForRowAtIndexPath.` When the cell is selected you call begin/end updates. In a `heightForRow` you set the height required to show content of the cell properly. In order to know what cell should be redrawn, just have an array of your indexPaths that are currently selected.

Comment: So, I tried but is does not work. Meaning the height is still good but the strange behaviour on the sections and the position of the cells is still here. I think the problem is linked to the reloading of the table view and the fact that it does not reconstruct the table properly. Moreover, I think `heightForRow` is useful before iOS 9; after auto-layout does this automatically.

Comment: Calling just `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` is absolutely correct and should work. The problem is probably somewhere else. Most likely in you `heightForRowAtIndexPath` or `estimatedHeightForRow...`. Most likely you are changing the height for all the cells or you are changing the height incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0` in `viewDidLoad()` for example. I had the same issue with animation with `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` and this helped. But in my case I use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a similar problem solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48795263/5644794).

This is far simpler than the linked answer. You'll want to add `tableView.setNeedsLayout()` in between the update methods. This tells the table view to layout at the end of the update cycle.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Change text
    ...

    // Update height
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.setNeedsLayout()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```